# WCF not honoring RequestFormat

Tags: c#, wcf

Trying to create a simple WCF service that behaves as a restful endpoint.  Hoping someone can see what I'm missing.

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method ="POST", UriTemplate = "TestJson", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
        string TestJson(CompositeType composite);
```

And From postman I get

> Cannot process the message because the content type 'application/json' was not the expected 'text/xml; charset=utf-8'

Comment: Is there a service binding defined in the web.config?

Comment: No, I just have binding="basicHttpBinding"

Comment: use a webBinding

Comment: rene, that seemed to do it, thank you!  I had to add <webHttp/> within that behavior as well. if you want credit for the answer go ahead... otherwise I'll post the answer a bit later

Answer (score 0):

i guess something is wrong with your `web.config` file. you should add `basicHttpBinding` for soap service and `webHttpBinding` for restful service. if you want them both you should add `mexHttpBinding` too. something like this:

```
<bindings>
    <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="SoapBinding" />
    </basicHttpBinding>
    <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="RestBinding" />
    </webHttpBinding>
    <mexHttpBinding>
        <binding name="MexBinding" />
    </mexHttpBinding>
</bindings>
```

then you can make json format as your default format like this:

```
    <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Web">
            <webHttp helpEnabled="true" defaultBodyStyle="Bare" defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json" automaticFormatSelectionEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
    </endpointBehaviors>
```

now you are good to go. just remember set content-type in your request header.